# Angular Material: How to combine ngIf, aria-label and i18n?

Tags: angular-material

I have the following compontent

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-placeholder i18n="@@Title4Version">Title for version</mat-placeholder>
   <input matInput [(ngModel)]="workflowInfo.title" readonly [readOnly]="lockTitle">
   <button mat-button matSuffix mat-stroked-button aria-label="Unlock" (click)="lockTitle=!lockTitle">
        <ng-container *ngIf="lockTitle; else unlocked">
          <mat-icon>lock_open</mat-icon>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #unlocked>
          <mat-icon>lock</mat-icon>
        </ng-template>
   </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

Which looks like the following screen shot:

[image]

My question: Is it possible to

1. Click on the lock button and enable the editing AND
2. have the `aria-label` accordingly set (i.e. either 'Unlock' or 'Lock') AND
3. have this label as well ready for i18n

I have an idea how to accomplish question 1 but how to have the other 2 options as well? Is it possible to have them all in one template? If not how to split them up `properly` (without code duplication)?

Answer (score 3):

You already have most of the code in place - just bind the aria-label attribute to an expression:

```
[attr.aria-label]="lockTitle ? 'Unlock' : 'Lock'"
```

And you appear to already be using template translations so you can probably use the translate attributes feature: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#translate-attributes.

```
i18n-aria-label
```

Comment: More than one way but you appear to already be using template translations so you can probably use the translate attributes feature: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#translate-attributes.

Comment: I looked around and still have a problem. With the attribute I can set or unset the aria-label, title, tooltip or whatever. But the text I set cannot be used for i18n translation, i.e. for the `[attr.aria-label]` how to set the content that it could be used in English and German - if translated? I don't see the option there. Something like `'Unlock@@UnlockTextField'` fails...

Comment: If you post a working stackblitz example I can take a look at it.